# Chinese remainder theorem? how do we get this equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve $56x + 23 \equiv 0 \pmod {323}$

I understand that $323 = 17 \cdot 19$, and the CRT applies because $\gcd(19,17) \equiv 1$.

But in my solution key, it says solution modulo $17$ gives us the equation $5x + 6 = 0 \pmod{17}$.

And the solution modulo $19$ gives us the equation $-x + 4 = 0$.

Where do we get those two equations from?

Comment: 56 = 5 (mod 17),  23 = 6 (mod 17) etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't quite an answer, but a very strong hint:

$5 \equiv 56  \pmod {17}$ and $6 \equiv 23  \pmod {17}$

$-1 \equiv 56 \pmod {19}$ and $ 4 \equiv 23 \pmod {19}$